# Counting consecutive shift and days in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to display the number of consecutive Shifts and Days a team has worked. I have tried a number of solutions but just cannot get it quite right.

The data is Date, Shift, Crew.  There is a Day and Night Shift and 3 crews.
ConsecutiveShift and ConsecutiveDay are the fields I am trying to produce.  The output will be used to look at productivity based on the number of consecutive shifts/days worked.

Any help is very much appreciated

```
Dateop               Shift  Crew
2015-12-23 00:00:00  D      B Crew
2015-12-23 00:00:00  N      A Crew
2015-12-24 00:00:00  D      B Crew
2015-12-24 00:00:00  N      A Crew
2015-12-25 00:00:00  D      C Crew
2015-12-25 00:00:00  N      B Crew
2015-12-26 00:00:00  D      C Crew
2015-12-26 00:00:00  N      B Crew
2015-12-27 00:00:00  D      C Crew
2015-12-27 00:00:00  N      B Crew
2015-12-28 00:00:00  D      C Crew
2015-12-28 00:00:00  N      B Crew
2015-12-29 00:00:00  D      C Crew
2015-12-29 00:00:00  N      B Crew
2015-12-30 00:00:00  D      A Crew
2015-12-30 00:00:00  N      C Crew
2015-12-31 00:00:00  D      A Crew
2015-12-31 00:00:00  N      C Crew
2016-01-01 00:00:00  D      A Crew
2016-01-01 00:00:00  N      C Crew
2016-01-02 00:00:00  D      A Crew
2016-01-02 00:00:00  N      C Crew
```

**Desired Output** - First 3 columns are the original data, column 4 and 5 are the counts I am trying to produce

[image]

Comment: What's the DBMS (Sql Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)?

Comment: I don't understand your required output. Can you explain further? Why does consecutive reset at 5? Is that a hard limit or based on some kind of weekday window? Why is 30th = 1,6 instead of 1,1?

Comment: Could you paste the input data as text rather than a picture. Makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Database is SQL Server 2012.  Nick,  Sorry for the poor explanation (I know what I want, lol).  There are 3 Crews - A, B and C Crew.  Operations run 24/7, each crew work 12 hour shifts, 5 Days, 5 Nights, 5 Days off.  The shift counter will reset after each crew works their 5 days and then their 5 nights but the days will continue to 10 days and then reset when they have their days off.  The analysis I want to conduct is based on the number of days they have worked, maybe on their 3rd and 4th Night shift the crew is less productive etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should work, using window functions:

```
With cte As (
    Select DateOp, Shift, Crew,
        DateDiff(Day, DateOp, '2016-01-01') + Row_Number() Over (Partition By Crew, Shift Order By DateOp) As ShiftIsland,
        DateDiff(Day, DateOp, '2016-01-01') + Row_Number() Over (Partition By Crew Order By DateOp) As DayIsland
      From [YourTable])      
Select DateOp, Shift, Crew,
    Row_Number() Over (Partition By Crew, Shift, ShiftIsland Order By DateOp) As ConsecutiveShifts,
    Row_Number() Over (Partition By Crew, DayIsland Order By DateOp) As ConsecutiveDays
  From cte
  Order By Crew, DateOp, Shift;
```

Comment: Mendosi, you are the Man!!  Works perfectly, I just couldn't quite get the logic correct.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a basic `row_number()`.  For the data you have provided:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by shift, crew order by date) as consecutiveshift,
       row_number() over (partition by crew order by date) as consecutiveday
from t;
```

This at least returns the data that you have in your question.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for Crew A who have a break between 24 Dec and 30 Dec. This should reset their `ConsecutiveDay` to 1 on 30 Dec, but your query continues to increment it.

Comment: @mendosi . . . As *explicitly* stated in the answer, this returns the results provided in the question.  The OP doesn't clarify what happens with "missing" days, or even if that is possible in the data.

Comment: Actually h the OP did specify in a comment posted before your answer. "The shift counter will reset after each crew works their 5 days and then their 5 nights but the days will continue to 10 days **and then reset when they have their days off.**" the original question did also clearly say consecutive days in a few places.